# Amcharts - Remove balloon

Tags: amcharts

I've got a multi-axis chart with several lines in the graph.Currently as I move the mouse over the chart, several balloons appear at each point showing the values of the various lines at that point. At the same time, the legend at the bottom of the graph also displays values for these points. Is there a way I can disable the balloon text from appearing when I hover over the chart. The values appearing in the legend area is sufficient.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just insert `"showBalloon": false` for each graph. [Reference](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#showBalloon)

Answer (score 1):

use baloon object in graph option to enable and disable amchart baloon.

```
     "graphs": [
{
"valueAxis": "item1",
  "balloon": {
    "enabled": false
  }

]
```